# Magento 2 Show Login Popup [ Guest Checkout is disable ] Even Customer Already Login

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, customer

We set guest checkout disable to show login popup at cart when customer click on process to checkout.
But the problem is when customer is already login then also login popup show at cart page when click on process to checkout.